# How to count the number of clild elements with one parent in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

Im new to xquery and im trying to count the number of albums that each musician has.

My data is as follows:

```
<musicians>
    <musician type="band">
        <name>If These Trees Could Talk</name>
        <genre>Post-Rock</genre>
        <albums>
            <album year="2006">If These Trees Could Talk</album>
            <album year="2009">Above the Earth, Below the Sky</album>
        </albums>
    </musician>
    <musician type="solo">
        <name>Justin Bergh</name>
        <genre>Pop-Rock</genre>
        <albums>
            <album year="2005">Out of My Hands</album>
            <album year="2010">Lateralus</album>
        </albums>
    </musician>
    <musician type="band">
        <name>Tool</name>
        <genre>Progressive Metal</genre>
        <albums>
            <album year="1993">Undertow</album>
            <album year="1996">Aenima</album>
            <album year="2001">Lateralus</album>
            <album year="2006">10,000 Days</album>
        </albums>
    </musician>
</musicians>
```

The expected output:

```
2
2
4
```

My code currently:

```
for $n in //musicians/musician/albums
let $count := count($n)
return $count
```

My output is

```
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently counting the number of `albums` elements, while you're stated goal is to count the `album` elements.

Change your code as follows:

```
for $n in //musicians/musician/albums
let $count := count($n/album)
return $count
```

This yields the required output:

```
2
2
4
```